# Does rsync verify files copied between two local drives?

Tags: rsync, verification

I want to make a fresh new copy of a large number of files from one local drive to another.

I've read that rsync does a checksum comparison of files when sending them to a remote machine over a network.

1. Will rsync make the comparison when copying the files between two local drives?
2. If it does do a verification - is it a safe bet? Or is it better to do a byte by byte comparison?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

rsync always uses checksums to verify that a file was transferred correctly.  If the destination file already exists, rsync may skip updating the file if the modification time and size match the source file, but if rsync decides that data need to be transferred, checksums are **always** used on the data transferred between the sending and receiving rsync processes.  This verifies that the data received are the same as the data sent with high probability, without the heavy overhead of a byte-level comparison over the network.

Once the file data are received, rsync writes the data to the file and trusts that if the kernel indicates a successful write, the data were written without corruption to disk.  rsync does not reread the data and compare against the known checksum as an additional check.

As for the verification itself, for protocol 30 and beyond (first supported in 3.0.0), rsync uses [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). For older protocols, the checksum used is [MD4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD4).

While long considered obsolete for secure cryptographic hashes, MD5 and MD4 remain adequate for checking file corruption.

Source: the man page and eyeballing the rsync source code to verify.

Comment: I hate to burst everyone’s bubble but rsync only does check sum verification if the -c flag is added!

Comment: @clint No, the answer is correct. From the man page's explanation of the `-c` flag: "Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file checksum that is generated as the file is transferred, but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has nothing to do with this option's before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?" check."

Comment: @Kyle Jones - so that means when rsync exits, the file is completely received? This is different from scp which just sends the data and doesn't worry about if it is fully received before exiting, right?

Comment: This answer does not make it clear if it actually verifies the file after a copy. If the checksum is computed as the file is being received, then it is not a post-copy checksum and you cannot be sure that the file is written correctly. You would then need to perform an additional comparison.

Comment: @AndreMiller Thanks for the comment.  I've updated the answer to address that issue.

Comment: Down-voting because I don't like the fact that this answer is detailed well written and technically correct and at the same time so much off topic that it misleads readers. The problem is that the answer goes into great detail on what happens during _transfer_ while the questioner specifically states that he cares about _local copies_ and _not_ network transfers. I'm pretty sure Kyle Jones didn't want to mislead anyone but this answer (IMHO) does.

Comment: @ndemou "Always uses checksums" means for local copies as well as remote copies.  rsync's behavior isn't much different when it is copying locally; it still uses two process and uses the same protcol to communicate and transfer files between them.  The processes just happen to be running on the same machine.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I believe the question asks: "1) when copying locally does rsync add checks to verify that the copy is identical to the original and 2) how trustworthy are these checks?". You note that rsync spawns 2 processes: one reading the original and one writing to the copy and you also note that the transfer of bytes _between these processes_ is checksummed. But this is marginally (if at all) helpful in guaranteeing the correctness of the copy because the probability of disk related issues corrupting the data is extremely higher that the probability of CPU/RAM issues.

Comment: @ndemou The answer covers the lack of verification of the disk data after it is written.  The OP accepted the answer.

Comment: Kyle I don't believe you answer is wrong. I already noted it's _"detailed well written and technically correct"_ but it requires the reader to be unnecessarily focused and careful. Why cover the lack of verification of the disk data which is being questioned halfway through your answer after 117 words which repeatedly describe an other irrelevant verification process? Anyway thanks for your time and interest in this discussion. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Almost four years later, but I somewhat agree with @ndemou. I think it would be best to preface the whole thing with a sentence that indicates "checksum always for transfer, not for disk write". I read the whole answer, and didn't realize until the comments that I misread the second paragraph.

Comment: At the receiver end, if it does not re-read the data, how the checksum be verified? At the sender side, checksum is calculated. Then sending [file + its checksum]. Receiver (either another harddisk or over the network) gets [file + its checksum] and write the file on to disk. The receive has to calculate the checksum of her received file, then verify her own calculation against the received checksum. Isn't it?

Comment: I thought the default check was file  size, date , name etc unless specified otherwise, that’s is, ‘-c' the checksum check.

Comment: @AndrewC Those checks determine whether the remote file should be updated. Checksums are used to verify transferred file contents even if you don’t specify -c.

Answer (score 61):

`rsync` does **not** do the post-copy verification for local file copies. You can verify that it does not by using `rsync` to copy a large file to a slow (i.e. USB) drive, and then copying the same file with `cp`, i.e.:

```
time rsync bigfile /mnt/usb/bigfile

time cp bigfile /mnt/usb/bigfile
```

Both commands take about the same amount of time, therefore `rsync` cannot possibly be doing the checksum—since that would involve re-reading the destination file off the slow disk.

The `man` page is unfortunately misleading about this. I also verified this with `strace`—after the copy is complete, `rsync` issues no `read()` calls on the destination file, so it cannot be checksumming it. One more you can verify it is with something like `iotop`: you see `rsync` doing read and write simultaneously (copying from source to destination), then it exits. If it were verifying integrity, there would be a read-only phase.

Comment: "The man page is unfortunately misleading about this. I also verified this with strace" Did you strace the remote, running rsync process or the local one? There are two... one runs on the destination, even when you use ssh.

Comment: There is no post-copy verification for any copies, local or remote.  You run `rsync -c` again if you want to force it to check.

Comment: The verification is done on the incoming stream as it goes. It's not necessary to read it back from the disk if the filesystem has confirmed it's been written.

Comment: rsync man page states "Note  that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file checksum that is generated as the file is transferred."

Comment: @openCivilisation, it looks correct, but so what? I myself got confused with that "receiving side" wording, just wrote an answer here for future reference.

Comment: I am sure the check is file size and dates by default unless `rsync -c` is specified to do the checksum check. Not sure if using a rsync server is any different.

Answer (score 22):

`rsync` makes a checksum comparison *before* copying (in some cases), to avoid copying what's already there. The point of the checksum comparison is not to verify that the copy was successful. That's the job of the underlying infrastructure: the filesystem drivers, the disk drivers, the network drivers, etc. Individual applications such as `rsync` don't need to bother with this madness. All `rsync` needs to do (and does!) is to check the return values of system calls to make sure there was no error.

Comment: This seems to contradict the accepted answer...

Comment: @djule5 In what way? The accepted answer seems to mostly be about how rsync checks **transferred** files, but the question, and my answer, are about **local** copies.

Comment: Ok, well in that context I agree it makes more sense. So _"The point of the checksum comparison is not to verify that the copy was successful"_ is true only for **local** copies; and _"checksums are always used on the data transferred between the sending and receiving rsync processes"_ is true only for **transferred** copies. I find the [accepted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30975/82895) misleading in regard to the question and believe your answer should be the accepted one (just my 2 cents).

Comment: I still feel this answer is slightly misleading. For example, it says that the network drivers in particular verify if the copy was successful - but if you were saying that checksum comparison does not verify if the copy was successful for local only, network drivers would not come into play.

Comment: @Ken I don't understand the point you're trying to make. I suspect you misread something. The network drivers come into play only if there's a network copy. Rsync itself does a checksum comparison *before* doing any copy, in order to decide whether to copy. Rsync doesn't do any checksum comparison *after* copying (because it would be pointless: it knows what it's just copied).

Comment: From what I understand about rsync, that's not true. It only checksums before the copy if you use the checksum option -c, but it always checksums after network copy to verify it was transfered properly.

Comment: @Gilles the transfer method is identical for local copies, the data stream just doesn't go through a network interface between the two processes.

Answer (score 17):

Quick and dirty answers, directly to the questions.

**Q:** Will `rsync` make the comparison when copying the files between two local drives?

> **A:** It will do comparison to figure out what to copy.

**Q:** If it does do a verification - is it a safe bet? Or is it better to do a byte by byte comparison?

> **A:** as safe as the mathematics behind MD5 checksum of file.  You can try to do simple experiment to learn and trust the tool.

Long answer:  I guess, you wanted `rsync` to do file comparison (bit by bit or by checksum) after copying files.  If you are one of the few that value data integrity, you might find the below useful:

```
rsync -avh [source] [destination] && rsync -avhc [source] [destination]
```

The above code `rsync` files folder on first run and if complete without issue, will run `rsync` again immediately while performing same file name comparison by using hash of entire file.

Comment: The last paragraph is not clear English (sorry no offence intended).  Are you saying that those options will cause ‘rsync’ to run twice?   Or that the user should run it a second time?

Comment: yes, that one liner would run rsync twice pending the result of the first run.

Comment: rsync doesn’t always use a checksum the documentation also mentions checks using just file dates and size.

Comment: @AndrewC, that's why the second part of that one liner is forcing rsync to check source and destination using checksum of the entire file instead of relying on mtime/size

Comment: Why not to run only second part ( `rsync -avhc [source] [destination]` )? What is the advantage of running both parts?

Answer (score 8):

### Using rsync to verify the integrity of a duplicate

*To guarantee that this test physically re-reads the files from the drive media, I suggest powering-down both drives and restarting them before running this test.  This will clear their internal volatile caches.*

If not also restarting Linux, you should at least drop the caches ([*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87908/6764)) with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Then to re-read both trees and compare their checksums:

```
rsync --dry-run --checksum --itemize-changes --archive SRC DEST
```

---

Modern rsync checksum uses MD5, which is 128 bits.  The likelihood of this failing to detect an error in an individual file is astronomically low (some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4927736)), but not impossible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493525/rsync-what-means-the-f-on-rsync-logs

Comment: Good luck getting the trailing slashes right.

Comment: No news is good news.

Comment: Don't bother with `--checksum` until the test has passed without it.

Comment: Why commenting yourself when you can edit the answer? If they were answer to some other comments, those are gone so yours confuse readers (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to clarify confusion I had myself and which is (IMO) difficult to understand from comments to accepted question. `rsync` man page states:

> Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was
> correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file
> check‐
> sum that is generated as the file is transferred

It is probably correct, but it does *not* mean the actual written files data are checked after copy. First, with local drives both sides are one PC (so `rsync` might skip the check if side is the same); second, checksum "is generated as *the file is transferred*" (emphasis mine), not as being written to the media.

P.S. I've just investigated my finding that after copying with `rsync` I've got files with mismatched checksums (I copied on glitchy PC I knew that beforehand but from reading man page thought `rsync` would make sure files are copied properly) and found that QA.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `rsync` you can use `cp -rp` to recursively copy a directory, followed by `diff -r`. GNU diff accepts two directory trees, which are both read in full when compared.

Rationale (thanks @they): both `cp` and `diff` are usually already installed and quite suitable for a onetime action like OP's *"I want to make a fresh new copy of a large number of files from one local drive to another."*

Comment: What is the reasoning behind using `cp` _in place of_ `rsync`?

Comment: It is already installed and quite suitable for a one-time action like OP's _"I want to make a fresh new copy of a large number of files from one local drive to another."_

Comment: +1 for answering the requirement

Comment: Note that by changing from `rsync` to `cp`, you are depending on the capabilities of the local `cp` utility to support the non-standard option `-r`, and you assume that it will do exactly what `rsync` would do (on some systems, the `-r` option would cause symbolic links to be followed, not copied as-is).  You also remove the ability to copy hard links and sparse files (again, depending on the `cp` implementation), which would be done portably using `rsync` with its `-H` and `--sparse` options.

Comment: Agreed that it is different. Point of this answer is: in many cases you don't need `rsync` but you can just get the job done with tools that are already installed. In case of hard links and sparse files, `cp` has options for those too, but those go beyond the requirement of the question which is to just copy a bunch of files from one local drive to another.
BTW I have to disagree with the recursive flag being non-standard in the copy command. With diff that is different, which is why the answer states GNU diff.

Comment: are the differences these days mainly between BSD vs GNU?