# Does sync command remove the dirty cache in the memory?

Tags: linux, memory

I am aware that sync command flushes the dirty cache into disk. I have run `free` command first, then `sync`, and then `free` again. The result of latter `free` command shows more free memory available than the former one.

Does this mean that the dirty caches are removed from memory when performing `sync`? Can anybody give me a more solid proof?

Comment: Related: [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

Answer (score 1):

No, It don't. I checked it myself many times, but don't worry, Linux kernel takes care of your precious memory very smartly.
read [Content cached in RAM while writing to disk - Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210950/content-cached-in-ram-while-writing-to-disk-linux/)
 and http://linuxatemyram.com

Answer (score 0):

This will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, dentries and inodes from memory, causing that memory to become free.

To free pagecache:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To free dentries and inodes:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

As this is a non-destructive operation, and dirty objects are not freeable, the user should run "sync" first in order to make sure all cached objects are freed.

Comment: Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Answer (score 0):

They are not :-).  Here is solid proof:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.409106 s, 256 MB/s
$ sync
$ time cat test > /dev/null

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.026s
```

The data was still cached after `sync`.  You can tell it was cached by looking at the time to read the file.  (I have a spinning hard drive, max read speed is around 100MB/s).  Compare this to the combination of `sync` and `drop_caches`:

```
$ sync
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
1
$ time cat test > /dev/null

real    0m1.030s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.073s
```