# Content cached in RAM while writing to disk - Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, file-copy

I have been facing this issue ever since I started using Linux distributions. While copying/moving either graphically or with `cp`, one/many big content (anything like a big text file, tar.gz archive, ISO image file, and movies), some part of the content is written to disk and some part cached in memory (RAM). During the copying time, the amount of shared and cached memory dramatically increased (checked with `free -m`).

After some time the file manager (like [Dolphin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_(file_manager)) or [PCManFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMan_File_Manager)) or `cp` shows that copying is finished, but data is actually not written to disk until I do a `sync`

I think this is not a hardware issue.

- I checked with many internal and external hard drives, and USB flash drives of various brands, but all with the same result.
- Not a [hard drive APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Power_Management#In_ATA_drives) issue. I always disable hard drive power management.
- The problem is same with dd and cat, like `dd if=live.iso of=/dev/sdb`.
- Not a distribution-specific issue. I checked with Debian, [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), Ubuntu, [Slax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slax), etc.
- I have not crosschecked with other Unix-like OSes. If anyone have/had the same issue with [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD), [OpenBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD), etc. please let me know.

**What is the problem and how can I solve it?**

Comment: It is not a problem, but a feature. http://linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: okay , got it , but I want that data to be written on the disk, like making a live USB, taking a movie from a friend etc and I want it as fast  as possible. Is there any workaround to avoid/disable it ?

Comment: You might use some `mount`  options. You should `umount`  a media (e.g. your USB key) before unplugging it (that would flush the data to the disk). You could continue using `sync`

Comment: Everything explained very well at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html , I will stick with `sync` . Thank you for your comment , will you consider to write it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented (and for obvious performance reasons) the kernel is using a [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). So this is a feature, not a problem. See http://linuxatemyram.com/ for more.

You could (but I don't recommend doing that) using some `mount` options (to disable, or lower the use of, the page cache), and you need to `umount` any device (e.g. an USB key) before unpluggging or removing it. Then the kernel would flush all the data before unmounting.

You can also do a `sync`.

Answer (score 2):

It is by design that the kernel tells userspace utilities that a file operation completed successfully while the caches are buffered.

Try editing /etc/hdparm.conf to disable write caching with the option `write_cache = off`. However this will reduce performance, and it is usually preferred to use `sync` if you want to ensure write buffers are flushed to disk.

Comment: /etc/hdparm.conf says `write_cache = off` for IDE drives , though disabled write-cache temporarily with `hdparm -W 0 /dev/sda` but this is even worst, laggy performance. Anyway I will stick with `sync`.  but what is wrong wiyh USB flash drives , they dont support write-caching ?

Comment: `write_cache = off` in `/etc/hdparm.conf` only disables the write cache in the **drive**, it doesn't affect the kernel's caches.