# Linux empty buffer cache command permission denied

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, permissions, memory

I'm using the following commands to flush cache:

```
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

When I use one of the above commands, I get the following:

```
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

My system  running CentOS 6.5, I logged in as root via SSH.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why are you're running the 3 commands, when the first one is all you need:

```
$ sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

This will do the following 3 things: free pagecache, dentries and inodes. Using 1 only frees the pagecache while 2 frees the dentries + inodes.

You're probably experiencing some weird timing issue where:

1. You're doing this operation too quickly
2. There is nothing to empty since you just previously ran the command
3. Your previous command hasn't had a chance to complete or be processed

#### References

- [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system/87909#87909)

Answer (score 2):

this one should work regardless the linux distribution you are running. You need to cover the redirection when running sudo.

```
$ sudo sh -c "$(which echo) 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Credits: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148442/101951
(i added the `which echo` part though)

Answer (score -1):

Simply you should try this

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

but you one is also working with me Same situation here but works fine

`[root@I-IDS ~]# w
 20:56:35 up  4:03,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.11
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     tty4     -                16:55    3:48m  0.25s  0.25s -bash
root     pts/0    192.168.1.42     20:55    0.00s  0.20s  0.00s w
[root@I-IDS ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
[root@I-IDS ~]# sy
sync          sysctl        sys-unconfig

[root@I-IDS ~]#  sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
[root@I-IDS ~]#  sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
[root@I-IDS ~]#  sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
[root@I-IDS ~]#  sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

can you please post our teminal output here from entering command to output

Comment: just for improvement in me may i know y this  got depreciated

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers other than the fact it is not in English...

Comment: Also whats the point of `sudo` before `echo`?

Comment: Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers are expected to be in English. But also, “Try this” followed by a command is not an answer. If you’re just guessing, don’t post an answer. If you’re sure that this is a correct answer, explain why it works.  Answers without explanations are subject to deletion.