# "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches" - Permission denied as root

Tags: linux, permissions, virtualization, proc, openvz

I am currently having some issues with the cache. It is a little too much right now so I wanted to clear it. I googled and found this little command: `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.
I am logged in as root over SSH (not using sudo). These are the attempts I made:

```
root@server: ~ # ll /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 15. Jan 20:21 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

root@server: ~ # echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

root@server: ~ # sudo su -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

root@server: ~ # echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
tee: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
3
```

It is a remote machine running Debian. As far as I know there are some vCores in this machine and it uses Virtuozzo for the virtualization.
I really just want to clear the cache *(So I can only access it using SSH)*.
I also tried registering this as a cronjob. But it simply fails too!

Comment: Are you running this as root or are you using `sudo`?

Comment: I am running this as root. But sudo also fails.

Comment: Does not work either. Already tried it. Same error message.

Comment: See the slm's A on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106887/linux-empty-buffer-cache-command-permission-denied), it might help.

Comment: This is extremely unlikely, but you never know, does `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` actually exist?

Comment: @terdon Yes. See my edit!

Comment: Is it a virtual server? openvz?

Comment: As far as I know it is a server with some vCores.

Comment: Is the cache causing you a problem? Or does it just look to big? Cache will usually be dropped when memory is needed for something more urgent.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I am logged in as root over SSH...It is a remote machine running Debian.

Is it actually a remote machine, or a just a remote *system*?  If this is a VPS *slice* somewhere, (at least some forms of) OS virtualization (e.g. openVZ) won't permit this from within the container.  You don't run the machine, you just run your slice.

Comment: There is like ***no way***???

Comment: Probably not, since there wouldn't be much point in not permitting it if there were alternate methods that worked.

Comment: @BrainStone - I use OpenVZ, it's not possible!

Answer (score 66):

`sudo` has to cover whole the redirection so it can be completely executed by root:

```
$ sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```

Comment: this actually worked for me (with the right binary location for echo)

Comment: in OpenVZ not work

Comment: alternatively, you could use tee instead: `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Comment: @mchid, consider adding your comment as an answer. It also worked for me on Azure VM.

Comment: It's root already, see # at the beginning of line. Issue with sudo is worth noting, but for another question.

Comment: this worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

This is normal behavior under OS-level virtualization. This can only be executed by someone with root access to the hardware node.

With for example **OpenVZ**, you don't get your own kernel instance and as such, are restricted from performing commands like this.

All share the same page cache, so to drop caches of only your instance, the kernel must check if the page belongs to you **and** if the other instances aren't using this page too.

With another virtualization technique like **KVM** or **Xen** this might be working.

Comment: So I could/should/must contact my hoster to clear the cache for me? And how do I find out what "virtualisation technique" my system is on?

Comment: Yes, you may not come around this...

Comment: I am not shure if this is right. I am running some vm's at aws and Xen and i am able to drop_caches.

Comment: That's why I wrote that under some virtualization techniques it works, for example Xen.

Comment: It works also unter qemu and vmware. I'd propose to write 'under some virtualization techniques it doesn't work', because OpenVZ provides virtualization at kernel level, so it is a special case. And i am unsure about if it could be modified to do so.

Comment: The difference is between *OS virtualization* (OpenVZ, LXC) and *platform virtualization* (QEMU, Xen), both of which have advantages and disavantages vs. the other.

Comment: @bersch Xen uses an own kernel for VMs. OpenVZ does not. You can think of OpenVZ like a better "chroot".

Answer (score 12):

You can use `echo` piped to `sudo tee` to allow the proper permission needed when you need to echo as root.

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Use `tee --help` to list more options.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo sh -c "echo  3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"`

This command work for me without `/usr/bin/echo` in mchid answer. It was giving error `sh: 1: /usr/bin/echo: not found` . So used only 'echo'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to use sudo like this:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

My solution was to temporarily switch to root.  Obiously, that permission has to be enabled on your system:

```
sudo su -  #temporarily switch to root user
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
exit # Exit as root.
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a smilar VM settings with OpenStack and this works (running Debian):

```
sync && sudo sh -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"
```