# Disable buffering in a VM configuration

Tags: linux, virtualization, buffer

I am executing some benchmark using a DBMS and virtual machines. And I am using this command

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

on each Guest, and on each Host, before executing a query, to minimize the effect of cache/buffering on my execution time. If the data is cached/buffered the execution time for a query may vary depending on what query was executed before, because a part of the file used to answer the query might be in memory.

I saw this post:
[How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

But for me it's a little tricky to execute sync/drop caches after each query. I need to ask for every VM and for every physical server to sync/drop caches. I could write a script, and use SSH to do this, but I wonder if there's a way to keep the OS from buffering/caching the files because it would be easier for me.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on all the VMs (using KVM) and servers.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to **completely** disable caching. This would mean that every instruction that executes in a program would have to be fetched from disk, instead of loading the program into memory in whole blocks.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid caching for files used by a specific process? All I want is to garantee that the queries will cause the data to be fetched from the disk, and not from memory.

Comment: So if the program reads from the file a byte at a time, each read should go to disk instead of using the block that was read for the previous read? I suspect that's not what you want, either. You just want the cache to be flushed before the program starts.

Comment: Note that anything you do regarding the VM's cache probably won't affect the host's cache.

Comment: @Barmar I execute queries for my distributed dbms to understand what is the better way to partitionate the data. The dbms retrieves blocks of data at time. I execute a series of queries, and I need to repeat the execution of the same query many times in a row. If the blocks are in memory, the execution time will be slower, and I can't use it to compare with another query. I could restart the whole system everytime, but it would take me forever.

Comment: When I flush the cache, I do this for the VM and for each Host I use. I assume that some o blocks of the VDI file might be in memory while the hypervisor is reading/writing on it.

Comment: If you're getting “strange results”, it means your setup is **broken**. You've given so little information (not even the VM technology!) that we can't help you repair it.

Comment: If `sync` fixes the problem, then they aren't due to caching, but to [buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

Comment: This is the command that solves my problem:
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free

I don't actually get strange results. The results I am getting are expected, but I want to minimize the effect of caching/buffering the file system data. I am using KVM as my hypervisor. Both guests and hosts are using ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/ to mark all the files used by the database system as FADV_DONTNEED?