# List all files that are present in the cache

Tags: linux, files, memory, cache

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system) answers to the question on how to find the what is part of cache. However, in the `fincore` executable you have to pass the filename to check if it is part of cache.

Is there a tools or a method to find all the entries that are part of the cached memory without passing the filenames.

PS: We are running it in an embedded system, and running a for loop and passing all the files to `fincore` itself is a more time and memory consuming process. Hence, I’m looking for other methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any place where the kernel exposes the filenames associated with the blocks that it has cached.  According to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941371

The best you could probably do even with a custom kernel module would be to get a list of inodes and devices.  From there you would still likely need to walk the filesystem looking for those files.

You may then ask "But, how does `fincore` know about the files I've listed?"  Or you might not, but I found the method pretty clever, so here it is.  The `fincore` tool works by doing the following:

- calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on the given file (https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/source/browse/linux-fincore.c#260)
- calling [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) on the memory region returned by mmap (https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/source/browse/linux-fincore.c#279)

The `mincore` system call tells you whether the given pages of memory are in core memory (ie, would not cause a page fault when accessed).  Since `mmap` lazily loads the mapped file, and we haven't read any of the mapped region yet, any pages that *would not* cause a page fault must otherwise be part of our cache.