# Need something that is faster than "wc -l"

Tags: command-line, wc

For a really big file like 1GB `wc -l` happens to be slow. Do we have a faster way calculating the number of newlines for a particular file?

Comment: Buy faster disks? Given that each byte of the input must be inspected for its `0x0A`iness, I/O is doubtless the bottleneck.

Comment: If you suspect `wc` of having too much overhead you may try to implement your own `foreach byte in file: if byte == '\n': linecount++`. If implemented in C or assembler I don't think it'll get any faster, except perhaps in kernel space on an RTOS with highest priority (or even use an interrupt for that - you just can't do anything else with the system... allright, I digress ;-))

Comment: And just to get a feeling for the scale I did a quick `time wc -l some_movie.avi` on an uncached file, resulting in `5172672 some_movie.avi --
real    0m57.768s -- user    0m0.255s -- sys     0m0.863s`. Which basically proves @thrig right, I/O shatters your performance in this case.

Comment: Best way to show it's a disk IO bottlneck, do `time wc -l some_large_file_smaller_than_cache` twice in quick succession and see how fast the second operation is, then `time wc -l some_large_file_larger_than_cache` and see how the time doesn't change between runs.  For a ~280MB file here, the time goes from 1.7 seconds to 0.2 seconds, but for a 2GB file it's 14 seconds both times.

Comment: How slow is too slow for you? What does `/usr/bin/time wc -l <file>` say?What's your hardware? Is it faster if you run the command repeatedly? We really need more information ;)

Comment: @marcelm: Yes, caching definitively plays significant role, since when I repeat the process I get up to thousand times faster results as second attempt. As far as hardware is concerned, I tried this on different systems having SSD disk and non SSD disk, and having L1d, L1i, L2  and in some systems L3 level caching. The slowest results and greatest caching speedup I found on VPS with no SSD and 1GB of RAM where I executed plain `time wc -l file`, on a 130MB textual log file the first time for ~15s, and second time for less then 0.3s. With SSD disk and >1GB files execution time was <1s.

Comment: I have a superfast SSD on x64, `time wc -l 2gb_of_urand 8896625 /home/cat/2gb_of_urand 

real 0m0.768s
user 0m0.204s
sys 0m0.236s`

Answer (score 22):

You can try to [write in C:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4YRPdRXKFs)

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  int nread;
  size_t nfound=0;
  while((nread=read(0, buf, BUFSIZ))>0){
    char const* p;
    for(p=buf; p=memchr(p,'\n',nread-(p-buf)); nfound++,p++) {;}
  }
  if(nread<0) { perror("Error"); return 1; }
  printf("%lu\n", nfound);
  return 0;
}
```

Save in e.g., `wcl.c`, compile e.g., with `gcc wcl.c -O2 -o wcl` and run with

```
<yourFile ./wcl
```

This finds newlines sprinkled in a 1GB file on my system in about **370ms** (repeated runs).
(Increasing buffer sizes slightly increases the time, which is to be expected -- BUFSIZ should be close to optimal).
This is very comparable to the ~**380ms** I'm getting from `wc -l`.

Mmaping gives me a better time of about **280ms**, but it of course has the limitation of being limited to real files (no FIFOS, no terminal input, etc.):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
  struct stat sbuf;
  if(fstat(0, &sbuf)<0){ perror("Can't stat stdin"); return 1; }

  char* buf = mmap(NULL, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 0/*stdin*/, 0/*offset*/);
  if(buf == MAP_FAILED){ perror("Mmap error"); return 1; } 

  size_t nread = sbuf.st_size, nfound=0;
  char const* p;
  for(p=buf; p=memchr(p,'\n',nread-(p-buf)); nfound++,p++) {;}

  printf("%lu\n", nfound);
  return 0;
}
```

I created my test file with:

```
 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=file bs=1M count=1042
```

and added some test newlines with:

```
 $ echo >> 1GB
```

and a hex editor.

Comment: I was surprised at the mmap result TBH. I used to think mmaping was faster than read/write, but then I saw some linux benchmarks that showed the opposite. Looks like it is very true in this case.

Comment: mmap is going to get vastly better results on linux because it'll map to huge pages these days, and TLB misses are sloooowwwwwww.

Comment: There may be some benefit to reading different parts of the file in separate threads (e.g. with an OpenMP `for` loop) so that some progress might be made while one thread is stalled waiting for input.  But on the other hand, it might hamper I/O scheduling, so all I can recommend is to try it, and measure!

Comment: The `read()` version may benefit from read-ahead.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yeah, multithreading might speed it up. Also looking scanning two bytes at a time via a 2^16 look up tables provided a pretty good speed up last time I played with it.

Answer (score 18):

You can improve on the solution suggested by @pskocik by reducing the number of calls to `read`.  There are a *lot* of calls to read `BUFSIZ` chunks from a 1Gb file.  The usual approach to doing this is by increasing the buffer size:

- just for fun, try increasing the buffer-size by a factor of 10.  Or 100.  On my Debian 7, `BUFSIZ` is 8192.  With the original program, that's 120 thousand read operations.  You can probably afford a 1Mb input buffer to reduce that by a factor of 100.
- for a more optimal approach, applications may allocate a buffer as large as the file, requiring a single read operation.  That works well enough for "small" files (though some readers have more than 1Gb on their machine).
- finally, you could experiment with memory-mapped I/O, which handles the allocation as such.

When benchmarking the various approaches, you might keep in mind that some systems (such as Linux) use most of your machine's unused memory as a disk cache.  A while back (almost 20 years ago, mentioned in the [vile FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html)), I was puzzled by unexpectedly good results from a (not very good) paging algorithm which I had developed to handle low-memory conditions in a text editor.  It was explained to me that it ran fast because the program was working from the memory buffers used to read the file, and that only if the file were re-read or written would there be a difference in speed.

The same applies to `mmap` (in another case still on my to-do list to incorporate into an FAQ, a developer reported very good results in a scenario where the disk cache was the actual reason for improvement).  Developing benchmarks takes time and care to analyze the reasons for the good (or bad) performance.

Further reading:

- [Is using a bigger buffer useful?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163931/is-using-a-bigger-buffer-useful)
- [mmap() vs. reading blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972/mmap-vs-reading-blocks)
- [mmap, munmap - map or unmap files or devices into memory](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)  (shows a sample program)
- [13.7 Memory-mapped I/O](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) (The GNU C Library)
- [How to purge disk I/O caches on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551838/how-to-purge-disk-i-o-caches-on-linux)
- [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: You're overestimating the influence of buffer sizes above a certain threshold. Typically, increasing the buffer size beyond 4KB-ish doesn't help much, and may in fact be detrimental because it may push the buffer out of L1 cache. On my machine, testing with `dd`, using 1MB buffers is _slower_ than 8KB. The 8KB default value for wc is actually chosen pretty well, it will be close to optimal for a large range of systems.