# How does the diff command handle caching?

Tags: shell, command, diff, cache

I became curious when I was diffing two large (>326MB) files, and noticed that the second run took much less time than the first.  This was frustrating, since I was trying to *time* the second run, to see how long the diff took.  :)

The man page doesn't mention a cache, and searching for 'diff cache' seems to flood me with results for the *git* `diff` subcommand, which is not what I'm interested in learning about.  So, my question is:

Why did the second run of `diff largeFile1 largeFile2` take so much less time than the first?  Where can I find more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` isn't doing any caching. The OS is. If you are using Linux, you can flush the disk buffers and cache. See [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I guess I shouldn't have given up after not finding a 'diff' directory under /var/cache.  I'll try to use that link to find more info.  'preciated.