# How can I optimize this Unix command?

Tags: command-line, awk, find, performance

The following command takes about 10 minutes to output the result

```
find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*" | xargs zcat |
    awk -F "|" '{if($14=="20160920100643" && $22=="567094398953") print $0}'| head
```

How can I improve its performance?

Comment: Can you use `locate` instead of `find` ? And If you want to stick with `find` then also use `exec` rather piping it to `xargs`

Comment: The answer depends on how many files there are, how they are distributed under `.`, and how large they are. Ten minutes could be a perfectly reasonable time.

Comment: Try sorting the input on column 14 before piping to awk

Comment: If you need just 10 first line (`head`) to speed up process do counting inside `awk`: `if(++count == 10) exit` but much better use `zgrep` instead all pipes.

Comment: @SHW ```xargs``` should be faster than ```-exec``` because it starts only one ```zcat``` process for many files. BTW ```xargs --max-procs=4``` could run it in parall.

Comment: If your awk is getting enough data to run on 100% CPU then you could speed-up by adding ```grep -F "567094398953"``` before awk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As noted in comments **zgrep** is better choice for such kind of tasks with **globstar** option which allows to use `**` as `all path inside the directory except hidden`

```
shopt -s globstar
zgrep -m 10 '^\([^|]*|\)\{13\}20160920100643|\([^|]*|\)\{7\}567094398953' ./**muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Recursive globbing is primarily a `zsh` feature, `shopt -s gobstar` is `bash`-only syntax. `**muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*` is `fish` only syntax. With `zsh` or `bash -O globstar` or `ksh93 -o globstar`, you need `**/muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*`. In any case, using shell recursive globbing is *not* going to be more efficient than using `find`. `zgrep` is inneficient as it runs one gzip and one grep per file.

Comment: Does not work if there are too many files (```xargs --show-limits```).

Comment: Hi Costas, this worked with just a little twick, got the output in 4 mins. Don't really understand your command but it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: zgrep '\([^|]*|\+\)\{13\}20160920100643|\+\([^|]*|\+\)\{7\}567094398953' **muc*_*_20160920_*.unl* | head

Comment: Will appreciate a little explanation, most especially the {13\} and {\7}

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: @JJoao, it's wrong in many ways: `zgrep -c 10 ...` counts the number of lines that contain `10` which is not asked for. It's not how globstar works that code only looks for `*muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*` files in the current directory only. `zgrep` is inefficient especially for small files as it runs one gzip and one grep command per file. That regexp is expensive.

Comment: It's also not anchored at the start, it doesn't check for the presense of a | or end-of-line after the 22nd field. The `|\+` doesn't make sense and would cause problems with empty fields. You'd need `zgrep -E '^([^|]*\|){13}20160920100643\|([^|]*\|){7}567094398953(\||$)'`

Comment: when I run the command alone it gives output, but when I put it into a shell script no output. Any advise?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you.  I see your point -- too many typos (`**/muc...` , `grep -m 10`, reg. expression, "**" is very slow, ....)  Nevertheless I learned with it (that is why I upvoted it)

Comment: @costas,@StéphaneChazelas,@JJoao: you guys have been very helpful. If I run the commands you guys provided alone it gives output, but if I try using it in a shell script it gives no output. pls advise

Answer (score 4):

That's already quite optimised. It's hard to know what the bottle neck is without knowing more details like:

- type of storage (HD, SSD, network, RAIDed)
- number and average size of matching files
- number of directories and other non-matching files
- number of fields in each line
- average length of a line

Things you can do in any case:

- replace `-print | xargs` with `-exec cmd {} +` or `-print0 | xargs -r0` if your `find`/`xargs` support  it. `-print | xargs` is not only wrong but also more expensive as `xargs` needs to decode characters to find out which ones are blanks and do some expensive quote processing.
- fix the locale to C (`export LC_ALL=C`). Since all the characters involved here (`|` and decimal digits for the file contents and latin letters, period and underscore for the file names) are part of the portable charset, if your charset is otherwise UTF-8 or some other multi-byte charset, switching to C with its single-byte charset will safe a lot of work for `find` and `awk`.
- simplify the `awk` part to: `awk -F "|" '$14 == "20160920100643" && $22 == "567094398953"'`.
- since you're piping the output to `head`, you may want to disable output buffering for `awk` so that it outputs those 10 lines as early as possible. With `gawk` or `mawk`, you can use `fflush()` for that. Or you could add a `if (++n == 10) exit` in `awk`.

To sum-up:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*" -exec zcat {} + |
  awk -F "|" '$14 == "20160920100643" && $22 == "567094398953" {
    print; if (++n == 10) exit}')
```

If CPU is the bottle-neck, on a multi-core GNU system, you could try:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*" -print0 |
  xargs -r0P 4 -n 100 sh -c '
    zcat "$@" | 
      awk -F "|" "\$14 == "20160920100643" && \$22 == "567094398953" {
        print; fflush()}"' sh | head)
```

To run 4 `zcat | awk` jobs in parallel on 100 files batches.

If that `20160920100643` is a time-stamp, you may want to exclude files that have been last-modified before that. With GNU or BSD `find`, add a `-newermt '2016-09-20 10:06:42'`.

If lines have a great number of fields, you get a penalty for `awk` splitting it and allocating so many `$n` fields. Using an approach that only  considers the first 22 fields could speed things up:

```
grep -E '^([^|]*\|){13}20160920100643(\|[^|]*){7}\|567094398953(\||$)'
```

instead of the `awk` command. With GNU `grep`, add the `--line-buffered` option to output the lines as early as possible in the parallel approach or `-m 10` to stop after 10 matches in the non-parallel one.

To sum up, if CPU is the bottle neck and you have at least 4 CPU cores on your system and there are at least 400 muc* files and you're on a GNU system (where `grep` is usually significantly faster than GNU `awk`):

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*" -newermt '2016-09-20 10:06:42' -print0 |
  xargs -r0P 4 -n 100 sh -c '
    zcat "$@" | 
      grep --line-buffered -E \
        "^([^|]*\|){13}20160920100643(\|[^|]*){7}\|567094398953(\||$)"
  ' sh | head)
```

Note that in the parallel approach, you may get the output of the `grep` commands inter-mingled (though with line-buffering and provided lines are less than a few kilobytes large, line boundaries should be preserved).

Comment: Maybe you  can also play with ```xargs -n 100``` to let the first ```zcat``` start earlier. Generally it's worth to note that if ```awk``` is not running on 100% CPU then we don't need to optimize ```awk``` at all but the command earlier in the pipe and so on.

Answer (score 0):

@Stéphane Chazelas's answer provides a great many details on how you can optimize the command pipeline

```
find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*" | xargs zcat |
    awk -F "|" '{if($14=="20160920100643" && $22=="567094398953") print $0}'| head
```

I'm going to provide another way to approach the problem where you actually measure where you're spending the most time.  Once you find where the time is spent, you can determine what to do about it.  If you want to improve your 10-minute run time, optimizing a step that takes 2 seconds is almost useless.

When I look at the command pipeline, three things draw my attention:

1. `find .` - What is the directory structure like?  How many files per
   directory?  Is the directory local to the system the command is being run on? A remote filesystem is going to be a *lot* slower.
2. `-name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*"` - How close are all the
   file names in the directory structure?  Are they all "close" to the
   name and difficult/CPU intensive to match?  Because *every* file in
   the directory tree has to have its name read from disk and compared
   to the pattern.
3. `xargs zcat` - The `xargs` doesn't seem to me that it will be too much of a performance problem, especially compared to the `find` issues above and the `zcat` itself.  Even if it's 10,000 or even 10,000,000 file names, the time used in passing and parsing just the names is almost certainly negligible compared to the time spent *finding* the names and then opening and decompressing all the files themselves. How large are the files?  Because you're decompressing the
   entirety of *every* file that matches your `find`'s filename
   pattern.

How can you determine what's the major performance problem?  Measure the performance of each command in the pipeline.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294554/how-to-use-gnu-time-with-pipeline for details on timing an entire pipeline.)  You can run the following commands and see how much time each step contributes to the processing time for the entire pipeline:

**`/usr/bin/time find .`** - This tells you how long it takes to run through your directory tree.  If this is slow, you need a better storage system.  [Flush your filesystem cache[s]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system) before timing this to get a worst-case measurement, then run the timed `find` again and see how much caching impacts performance.  And if the directory isn't local, try running the command on the actual system that the files are on.

**`/usr/bin/time find . -name "muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*"`** - This will tell you how long it takes to pattern-match the file names.  Again, flush filesystem cache[s] and run it twice.

**`/usr/bin/time bash -c "find . -name 'muc*_*_20160920_*.unl*' | xargs zcat > /dev/null"`** - This is the one I suspect is the major component of your pipeline's long running time.  If this is the problem, parallelizing the `zcat` commands per Stéphane Chazelas answer may be the best answer.

Continue adding steps from the original command pipeline to the one being tested until you find where you're spending most of your time.  Again, I suspect it's the `zcat` step.  If so, perhaps the `zcat` parallelization that @Stéphane Chazelas posted will help.

Parallelizing `zcat` may not help - it may even *hurt* performance and slow processing down.  With only one `zcat` running at a time, IO may be in a nice streaming pattern that minimizes disk seeks.  With multiple `zcat` processes running at once, the IO operations may contend and actually slow down processing as disk heads need to seek and any read-ahead done becomes less effective.

If the `zcat` step is your major performance bottleneck, and running multiple `zcat` processes at one time doesn't help or actually slows you down, your pipeline is IO-bound and you need to address the problem by using faster storage.

And again - if the directory isn't local the machine your running the command pipeline on, try running it on the machine that the file system actually is on.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out, it is not possible to give the correct answer without some extra details.

```
locate -0 -b -r '^muc.*_.*_20160920_.*.unl.*gz' | 
   xargs -0  zcat |
   awk -F "|" '$14=="20160920100643" && $22=="567094398953"'| head
```

- 1: locate (if available) is much faster than `**` or `find`; The regular expression used must be tuned...
- 2 and 3: the PO's filter

As @rudimeier, wisely pointed out, there are issues regarding the availability and update state of `locate`. (eg in most linux machines locate is update daily; this way it will fail to find files created today)

Nevertheless if locate is available this will produce a very impressive speedup.

It would be interesting if the PO could provide the `time ...` of the various solutions

Comment: I don't think that ```locate``` is appropriate here. If there are really millions of files which makes find slow, then the locatedb is probably also big and slow. And locatedb updates (cron) may slow down the machine for hours or days.

Comment: @rudimeier,  if availlable (which happens by default in most of linux machines) **locate if very fast!**. It uses database indexing techniques.  In my machine (2 terabytes of files) a `locate` like the one presented in my answer, takes less than 1s; a similar find or "**" takes more than 1 hour just to search in my home/jj folder.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: My concern about locate is more because of reliability rather than speed. He is grepping for yesterday's dates! How to make sure that locatedb is up-to-date? BTW your zgrep is slower than the original  zcat (It's just a huge shell script which runs one zcat _per_file_). Moreover "-m10" is simply wrong.

Comment: @rudimeier, thank you for the comments. (1) you are right about "-m 10" - it may remove some relevant results (updated)

Comment: @rudimeier ...(2) about the difference about "zcat | head" and "zgrep | head" in my machine using files with more then 200_000 lines the times presented less then 10% of difference (not really important)

Comment: @yemmy, you said in a comment "if a run as a command it works; if I run in a script, no output". (1) is my solution working with your case? (2) its behavior should be the same in script. It is difficult to debug it without the script extract...