# How to analyze top command results: CPU & RAM consumption

Tags: performance, cpu, top, ram

I am working on ARM-based processor (OS version: Linux 3.4.35) and I need to analyze the processor's performance while some processes are running, by typing top command, I can see some statistics but I do not understand the details there, what information should I look for ?

Here the details I need to understand (difference between CPU usr and CPU sys, what is nic, idle, io irq and sirq and how to clear cached RAM):

```
Mem: 32184K used, 648K free, 0K shrd, 676K buff, 7536K cached
CPU: 11.7% usr 29.4% sys  0.0% nic 41.1% idle 11.7% io  0.0% irq  5.8% sirq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to get started with learning about a given Linux/Bash command is to reference the manual page or manpage of the given command.

[Here is a link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) to a `top` manpage. In shell, you should be able to read the manpage by simply executing `man top`. I will also include a link to a [blog](https://www.booleanworld.com/guide-linux-top-command/) explaining `top`.

The relevant part to your question can be found at section **2b. TASK and CPU States** of the manpage:

> As a default, percentages for these individual categories are
>          displayed.  Where two labels are shown below, those for more recent
>          kernel versions are shown first.
>
> ```
>        us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
>        sy, system  : time running kernel processes
>        ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
>        id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
>        wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
>        hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
>        si : time spent servicing software interrupts
> ```

`us` and `ni` are the percentage of CPU usage spent on un-niced and niced processes respectively. Nice values are user space processes that are either nice or not in that they can be given a priority value that either cooperates and gets out of the way of more important kernel or system processes or does not. [Here is a link to a fairly straightforward explanation](https://askubuntu.com/a/656810) of niceness and priority.

The others should be rather straightforward:

`idle` is how much of the processor's capacity is idle or unused. `io` is the Input/Output queue of the processor. `irq` and `srq` are hardware and software interrupts respectively.

If you want more information on how to sort `top` output, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-sorted-by-actual-memory-usage) is a relevant Stack Overflow post. Additionally if you want to know more about clearing cached memory/buffers, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system) is a U&L stack exchange post.

Please read over all the links I have provided and if needed you should dig a little deeper and research more into how Linux processing and memory handling works. There is a wealth of information out there online.