# "buff/cache" is very high, how I can free it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, top

The output of the top command shows that 29GB of memory is used by "buff/cache". What does it mean and how I can free it? It is near to 90% of memory.

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Comment: Related: [How do you empty the buffers and cache on a Linux system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87908/315749)

Comment: Have you read https://linuxatemyram.com ?  If yes and you still have a problem, please edit to explain what problem you have, and show the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`.  If that's not the case, please say so, and a short answer might be written, because I can't find any other question to mark this one as a duplicate of :-).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You **don't need** to free "buff/cache".

"buff/cache" is memory that Linux uses for disk caching, and **that will be freed whenever applications require it**. So you don't have to worry if a large amount is being shown in this field, as it doesn't count as "used" memory.

Quoted from http://www.linuxatemyram.com (emphasis mine):

> Both you and Linux agree that memory taken by applications is "used", while memory that isn't used for anything is "free".
>
> But how do you count memory that is currently used for something, but can still be made available to applications?
>
> You might count that memory as "free" and/or "available". **Linux instead counts it as "used", but also "available".** (...)
> This "something" is (roughly) what top and free calls "buffers" and "cached". Since your and Linux's terminology differs, **you might think you are low on ram when you're not.**

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: i got a problem with WSL2 linux, it is cache in wsl linux, but it's the real amount of RAM that windows allocated for

Comment: So.. only check Used and compare it with Total?