# Verifying a large directory after copy from one hard drive to another

Tags: ubuntu, files, file-copy, file-transfer, checksum

I have a home file server that I use Ubuntu on.

Recently, one of my drives filled up so I got another and threw it in there.

I have a very large folder, the directory is about 1.7 T in size and contains a decent amount of files.

I used [GCP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gcp.1.html) to COPY the files from the old drive to the new one and it seems to have worked fine.

I want to now validate the new directory on the new drive against the original directory on the old drive before I delete the data from the old drive to free up space. I understand that I can do a CRC check to do this.

How, specifically, can I do this?

Comment: You might like to check there are no symbolic links or special files in your original folder with `find /origfolder ! -type f ! -type d -ls`. There should be no output.

Comment: (And also if any files are hard linked `find /origfolder -type f -links +1 -ls`. This is unlikely if the files are your own, and not from some downloaded software package, for example).

Comment: Related question: [verification - Does rsync verify files copied between two local drives? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/does-rsync-verify-files-copied-between-two-local-drives)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I’d simply use the `diff` command:

```
diff -rq --no-dereference /path/to/old/drive/ /path/to/new/drive/
```

This reads and compares every file in the directory trees and reports any differences. The `-r` flag compares the directories recursively while the `-q` flag just prints a message to screen when files differ – as opposed to printing the actual differences (as it does for text files). The `--no-dereference` flag may be useful if there are symbolic links that differ, e.g., in one directory, a symbolic link, and in its corresponding directory, a copy of the file that was linked to.

If the `diff` command prints *no output*, that means the directory trees are indeed identical; you can run `echo $?` to verify that its exit status is `0`, indicating that both sets of files are the same.

I don’t think computing CRCs or checksums is particularly beneficial in this case. It would make more sense if the two sets of files were on different systems and each system could compute the checksums for their own set of files so only the checksums need to be sent over the network.  Another common reason for computing checksums is to keep a copy of the checksums for future use.

Comment: Does diff work with any kind of file type? Like mkv/ogg for videos?

Comment: @PeterA That's correct. Diff works with *all* file types. It can provide more information about the specific differences between text files while for non-text files, it simply reports if there is any difference. BTW, I edited my answer with an extra sentence on the expected output of the command.

Comment: Thanks @meuh I've incorporated that into my answer -- and upvoted yours.

Comment: I have added a new answer that uses this answer with a bit of a twist. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554968/269618).

Comment: I'd use something like `screen` for both the copy and diff commands, especially if you're doing this over ssh.

Answer (score 17):

[rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rsync.1.html) is often used to copy files instead of `gcp`, but it can also be used to verify a copy, however it was made. Simply do

```
rsync -niaHc /origfolder/ /copyfolder
```

Be careful to end the first folder name (the source) with a `/`.
The options are

- `-n` do not copy (make no changes)
- `-i` itemise the differences
- `-a` preserve (i.e. compare since we have `-n`) permissions, ownerships, symbolic links, etc. and recurse down directories
- `-H` preserve hard links
- `-c` compare checksums

The output shows a code detailing the differences for each file or directory that differs. There is no output if they are the same. The code has columns `YXcstpoguax` where each character is a dot `.` if that aspect of the comparison is ok, or a letter:

```
Y is type of update: 
   < sent (not appropriate in this case)
   > need to copy 
   c missing file or directory
   h is hard link
   . no update
   * and rest of line is a message, eg *deleting
X file type: f file  d dir  L symlink  D device S special file
c checksum differs. + new item  " " same
s size differs
t timestamp differs
p permissions differ
o owner differ
g group differ
u (not used)
a acl differ
x extended attributes differ
```

For example,

```
.d..t...... a/b/                    directory timestamp differs
cL+++++++++ a/b/d -> /nosuch2       symbolic link missing
cS+++++++++ a/b/f                   special file missing (a/b/f is a fifo)
>f..t...... a/b/ff                  file timestamp differs
hf          a/b/xx1 => a/b/xx       files should be a hard linked
cLc.t...... a/b/z -> /tmp/hi2       symbolic link to different name
cd+++++++++ a/c/                    directory missing
>f+++++++++ a/c/i.10                missing file needs to be copied
```

See `man rsync` under `--itemize-changes` for more details. If you have differences in the 3rd `c` or 4th `s` columns, then you have serious data corruption. Other flags such as different permissions, owner or timestamps may be less important to you. If all the files are marked as "missing" then you have probably not given the right directories to compare. If you are sure, running rsync without the `-n` flag will "fix" the differences.

Comment: When I try this option, I get a lot of output, and it is not clear to me what it means.

Comment: I've added some examples and their meaning. See `man rsync`.

Comment: This apparently does not work if files were removed from origFolder or extra files are present in copyfolder.

Comment: To get this to work, I ran once as-is, and then re-ran swapping the paths. As always with rsync, note the trailing slash on the source path is significant.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and I used [Anthony's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313135/269618), with a bit of twist.

Applying directly his answer will fail in case of some hardware failure (like input/output error) which forces diff to exit.

I compiled his answer, along with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175393/1051589), and put it altogether into this:

```
find /path/to/original -type f -exec bash -c 'diff -rq --no-dereference "$@" "/path/to/destination/$(sed -r "s/^.*(<first-common-ancestor>.*)$/\1/g" <<<"$@")"' bash {} \;
```

- Replace `/path/to/original` with the path of the original directory you copied.
- Replace `/path/to/destination` with the path of the destination directory you copied to.
- Replace `<first-common-ancestor>` with the common ancestor directory between both. Example: you are copying from `/media/foo/bar` to `/media/test/dst/`, so that `dst`, after the copy operation is done, has the directory `bar`. The first common ancestor is `bar` here; because all files under `bar` will have the same relative path.

Some notes:

- The `bash -c` and `bash {}` parts are to perform safe substitution for files name; to be on the safe side not be harmed with possible attacks (like privilege elevation).
- The `sed` part is to remove the absolute path of the file found and use only relative path (this is different from using `execdir`). If you are not sure how this is useful, try removing it and check the error messages :)
- The `<<<` to read the variable as a string rather than reading it as a path to a file to read.

Comment: Upvoting for an impressive use of passing parameters to a shell command via the `-exec` option of `find`.  I'm guessing you ran into those hardware problems yourself and this answer is a case of scratching your own itch.  I was able to use this answer without the `sed` substitution by just providing an appropriate destination argument (`/media/test/dst/bar`). Finally, not all `diff` implementations have a `--no-dereference` option: it’s not specified by POSIX and not available in GNU diffutils 3.3.

Comment: Thanks man. Yep, I ran into more than a problem to build this up. Sorry I got your name misspelled :) Thanks for the upvote and taking the time to evaluate the answer.