# Check data integrity after copying thousands of files

Tags: storage, data, integrity

I copied thousands of files into an exFAT MicroSD card.

The number of files and bytes is identical, but how do I know whether the data is corrupt or not?

It would be good if the JackPal Android Terminal also supports the command.

Comment: See also *[Does rsync verify files copied between two local drives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30970)* (2012).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unmount, eject, and remount the device.  Then use

```
diff -r source destination
```

---

In case you used `rsync` to do the copy, `rsync -n -c` might be very convenient, and it is nearly as good as `diff`.  It doesn't do a bit-for-bit comparison though; it uses an MD5 checksum.

---

There are some similar answers with other details at: [Verifying a large directory after copy from one hard drive to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313089/verifying-a-large-directory-after-copy-from-one-hard-drive-to-another)

Comment: I like that. Unfortunately, Android Terminal lacks `diff`. Good nevertheless.

Comment: @neverMind9 Install Termux for diff,rsync,etc on Android.

Comment: @user1133275 Actually, the similar alternatives _`cmp`_ and `comm` are included in JackPal's terminal.

Comment: I tend to prefer `diff -rq ...` to suppress the diff output for any text files that may be present. I want to know _if_ there are differences, not necessarily _what_ the differences are.

Comment: @neverMind9 I think [toybox](https://www.landley.net/toybox/status.html) these day provides `diff`.

Comment: `rsync` can support many checksums. My version v3.2.3 on Arch Linux was compiled with xxh128 xxh3 xxh64 (xxhash) md5 md4.

Comment: I assumed offhand that `diff` would be faster than the `md5sum` solution as there are no calculations involved, but was surprised.  Both were CPU bound on my system, but `diff` is single-threaded and two `md5sum`s (or your hashing algo of choice) can be run in their own threads.  Maybe it's because I have fast disks and slow(er) CPUs, but if your use case is time-critical (e.g. I'm migrating production VMs off hours), try it both ways first to see the perf in your env. I got about 3.5min for MD5 and 4.6min for a diff on a 60GB volume. Considering I have 3TB to verify... it'll add up.

Answer (score 19):

Using MD5 sums is a good way, but the canonical way to use it is:

1. `cd` to the directory of the source files and issue:

   ```
   md5sum * >/path/to/the/checksumfile.md5
   ```

If you have directories with many levels, you can use `shopt -s globstar` and replace `*` by `**/*`.

Notice that the file specs in the MD5 file are exactly as provided in the command line (relative paths unless your pattern starts with a `/`).

2. `cd` to the directory of the copied files and issue:

   ```
   md5sum -c /path/to/the/checksumfile.md5
   ```

With `-c`, `md5sum` reads the file specs in the provided MD5 file, compute the MD5 of these files, and compares them to the values from the MD5 file (which is why the file specs are usually better left relative, so you can re-use the MD5 file on files in various directories).

Using MD5 sum this ways immediately tells you about MD5 differences, and also about missing files.

Comment: if the number of files goes into thousands, letting the shell do the wildcard expansion may cause troubles. Using `find -exec` is safer.

Comment: @peterph Either that or a loop such as `for` or `while`.  Shell built-ins are immune to `Argument list too long` error

Comment: Good remarks. OTOH `xargs --showlimits` says the max command line is around 2MB (2086956 bytes). `ls `./**/*.mp3` on my 21GB music collection (3600 files, kept as  Genre/Artist/Album/Title.mp3, so rather long paths) is 290K bytes. So this is not too likely to happen.

Comment: I recommend the answer to switch from using `md5sum` to `b2sum`. It is well-known that MD5 has been cryptographically broken (in collision resistence) for a long time. It was still used because of its speed. But these day [BLAKE2](https://blake2.net/) is faster than MD5 and secure (derived from SHA-3 finalist [BLAKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function))). A remark can be added to warn that older GNU/Linux system may not have `b2sum`.

Comment: @AlexVong Can't find b2sum for my 16.04.

Comment: @xenoid You can have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965525/what-packages-in-ubuntu-repositories-provide-blake2-sums-on-16-04

Comment: @xenoid So basically it isn't available for xenial. I guess you will have to use `shasum -a 512256 *` for the meantime.

Comment: @AlexVong No, because it is twice as slow as md5sum and we don't need crypto here. MD5 is good enough to catch copy errors.

Comment: @xenoid IMO, twice as slow is fine for shell scripts. Anyway, I think you should at least warn about not using MD5 for anything security-related.

Answer (score 8):

```
rsync -rc original-dir/ copied-dir/
```

`-c` causes rsync to compare files by MD5 checksum (without it, it normally uses only the timestamp and size for quicker comparisons).

This will also cause rsync to copy whatever it sees different or missing from the destination. To avoid that, you can also use `-n` and `-i`. The former ensures that rsync doesn't do any change and only compares, and the latter causes it to display the differences that it sees.

For example, I have the following dirs:

```
$ find dir1/ dir2/
dir1/ dir2/
dir1/
dir1/d
dir1/d/a
dir1/d/b
dir1/c
dir2/
dir2/d
dir2/d/a
dir2/d/b
```

And this:

```
$ rsync -rcni dir1/ dir2/
>f+++++++++ c
>fc.T...... d/b
```

Tells me, by way of all those `+`s, that file `c` does not exist in `dir2`, and file `d/b` does, but is different (indicated by the `c` in the first column). The `T` says that it's time would be updated (had we not used `-n`).

The format of `-i`'s output is described in the manpage for rsync. You can `man rsync` and get to the part that explains that output by typing `/--itemize-changes$` (and hitting Enter).

Answer (score 5):

Along with the other fine answers above, I would like to also recommend considering hashdeep, from http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/. It has a good sized userbase in the scientific community, where they frequently have to do this type of thing with terabytes of data scattered across thousands of directories.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to generate hashsums for individual files and output them into one text file, of which the MD5 hash can be generated. For that text file, you can use any hash function you like because this hash list's size is not large enough to cause any noticeable performance difference when using harder hash functions such as `sha512sum`. 
I use `cksum` due to it's universal availability (`sum` and `crc32` are not included in JackPal's Android Terminal) and maximum speeds. It is not a cryptographic, secure algorithm like `sha512sum`, but **any hash function** is good enough to verify data integrity in an offline environment. However, if you wish all file hashes to have the same length (i.e. 32), use `md5sum`, the fastest universally supported *secure* hash algorithm (although it is older, it is much faster than any *sha* algorithm and will do it's job).

#### Run these commands on both source and destination:

```
cksum /path/to/folder/* | tee -a hash.files.txt |cut -f 1 -d " " >>hash.list.txt #extracts pure hashsum string only for the output, to hide the different file path.
md5sum hash.list.txt
```

…or with a single command:

```
cksum /path/to/folder/* | tee -a hash.files.txt | cut -f 1 -d " " | tee -a hash.list.txt | sort | md5sum
```

The name of the hashsum list files (*hash.list.txt* and *hash.files.txt* in my example) can be anything you specify. Generating two files to be able to identify damaged files (the first file contains the file names as well, the second file is for comparison).

`sort` because `sh` and `bash` implement alphabetical sorting slightly differently. `sort` compensates for it.

Comment: In the end of `md5sum` manual it's stated explicitly: "Do  not  use  the  MD5 algorithm for security related purposes.  Instead, use an SHA-2 algorithm, implemented in the programs sha224sum(1), sha256sum(1), sha384sum(1), sha512sum(1), or the BLAKE2 algorithm, implemented in b2sum(1)" So this is not "secure".